# How can i change the base url of an application in yii1?

Tags: yii1.x

I'm new to the Yii Framework. I was given an application to work on at the office. How can I change the base url of an application in Yii1?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit /path/to/application/protected/config/main.php to change the default value. Add a request component, and configure baseUrl porperty.

```
    return array(
        ...
        'components' => array(
             ...
             'request' => array(
                 'baseUrl' => 'http://www.example.com',
              ),
         ),
      );
```